# Java package does not compile but some classes in that package can be used by other projects

Tags: c#, java

I am quite new to Java (but having C#.NET experiences for many years).

Exists there a comparison of the most important differences between Java/JRE and C#/.NET?

Discovered a "strange" behavior in a Java "solution". Having several projects in my workspace. One of the packages does not compile. But this package also contains classes which are used by other projects without problems.

So it seems to me that even when a class does not compile in a package the other classes in that package can be used by other projects?

Is a package comparable to an assembly (.dll) in .NET? In .NET when a class does not compile no .dll will be generated.

The other strange thing for me is that .class files are also checked into the source control system. Maybe is this the reason why classed from a non-compileable package can be used. Does it really make sense checking in .class files to source control?

Comment: It sounds like this question is really about your environment. No, it's not usual to check .class files into source control. As for non-compiling source - well, that depends on the compiler you use. Eclipse will allow you to generate class files even for broken classes.

Comment: For future questions, please ask only one question at a time. Linking between SO questions is fine, but one SO question should only contain one question. (Imagine what happens if someone answers just your 1st and 2nd questions, but leaves the 3rd one open - if you accept the answer, future visitors may not see that the 3rd sub-question is still open, and if you don't accept it, it looks like the answers to the first two sub-questions were incorrect or dissatisfying.)

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Well you're right! I got an huge Java legacy project and at the beginning it was difficult for me to distinguish what is related to that special project and what is related/usually to/in the Java world. I promise that I's do it better in the future ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the reverse, learning C# and have some java experience.  I would say packages in java are a little different than the .dll files generated in .NET.  The packages in java are compiled into individual class files.  So if one java source file doesn't compile in the package, you can use the other classes that did compile in that package (as long as the one that didn't compile isn't required by one of the other classes you are using).  I would say it doesn't make sense to checkin the .class files to source control.  I would just check in the java source files.

You may want to look at the folder structure that is generated by the package, that will give you a sense of what is being output.  Typically it works like this if your package is com.mycompany.myapp then you'll have a folder structure of com/mycompany/myapp and inside myapp folder you'll see the class files.  I'm sure someone else can provide more details, but I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, answers my question regarding to "class/method" of an package which doesn't compile entirely can be used by another project.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it really make sense checking in .class files to source control?

In general the consensus is that source control is for source code and other inputs to the compilation process.  Sometimes you might want to include a dependency (e.g. a 3rd party dll), but there's rarely a good reason to include your own output files.